# Limit of a double integral over the disk

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I am stuck with the following request.

> Compute
> $$
> \lim_{r\to+\infty}e^{-r}\int_{B(0,r)}e^{|x|+|y|}dxdy
> $$

For the integral, one gets

$$
\int_{B(0,r)}e^{|x|+|y|}dxdy=4\int_{0}^r\int_0^{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}e^{x+y}dxdy=4\int_{0}^r e^x(e^{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}-1)dx
$$

but with this integral I don't know how to proceed (I tried with $x=r\cos(\theta)$ with no success).

Comment: Using the polar system ($x=r\cos\phi;\,y=r\sin\phi$)
$$\lim_{r\to\infty}e^{-ar}\int_{B(0,r)}e^{|x|+|y|}dxdy=\lim_{r\to\infty}\int_{\frac1{\sqrt2}}^1\frac{dx}{x^2\sqrt{1-x^2}}\Big(e^{\sqrt2r(x-\frac a{\sqrt2})}\sqrt2rx-e^{\sqrt2r(x-\frac a{\sqrt2})}\Big)$$
$$=0\,\,\text{at}\,\,a>\sqrt2$$
At $a\in[0;\sqrt2]$ the limit is $\infty$

Answer (score 0):

Since $|x|+|y|=\sqrt{(|x|+|y|)^2}=\sqrt{x^2+2|x||y|+y^2}\ge\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, we have

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{B(0,r)}\mathrm e^{|x|+|y|}\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy
&\ge&
\int_{B(0,r)}\mathrm e^{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy
\\
&=&
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^r\mathrm e^rr\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\phi
\\
&=&
2\pi\left(\mathrm e^r(r-1)+1\right)\;,
\end{eqnarray*}

so the product goes to infinity.

Comment: Is the inequality $\sqrt{(x+y)^2}\ge\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ true?

Comment: @user64494: It isn't, thanks for spotting that. Now the inequalities should be OK.